# POP bandwidth increases every month because Outlook.com does not download and delete mails from my server when checking mail

Tags: outlook.com, pop3, bandwidth

I have a server with a domain on. I am using Outlook.com to connect to the server, via POP, and check my mail. The option to keep a copy of mail on the server is not and never has been checked.

Outlook.com should download the mail and leave the server empty, but it doesn't, the mail is still on the server. The problem is the bandwidth used for POP is increasing every month. Every month the bandwidth being used by that domain increases and it's all POP traffic, because I think Outlook.com is downloading all the mail from the server.

This month the POP traffic from this domain is 52GB, last month it was 33GB, the month before 20GB....

Can someone please tell me what I can do to stop this!?

I'm having the same problem on a few domains on this server (it's Hostgator).

Comment: Why not use IMAP?

Comment: @Fogest Outlook.com doesn't support IMAP

Comment: @Sathya He is using Hostgator, I also have Hostgator, and have no IMAP issues through Gmail. If Outlook does not support IMAP, it may be better for them to switch to another email provider such as Gmail.

Comment: I have experienced the same thing - Outlook.com setup to check external email accounts (with POP3 provided as the only option), but with the option to leave emails on the server. Since this was setup, we've been averaging around 1.5Gb of POP3 traffic every day. Microsoft support advised Outlook.com checks external accounts every 30 mins, which matches with my traffic graphs, but they say it a)downloads only 50 emails at a time and b)will only fetch new incoming emails. I suggested it's downloading all emails every time, but they dismissed that saying there'd be duplicates in the Outlook.com

Comment: ...con't... inbox if that was the case.

They provided me a link to to their [outgoing mail server IP addresses](http://mail.live.com/mail/ipspace.aspx), but could not give incoming server addresses. I'm waiting for the hosting co. to provide incoming traffic logs to check where all that POP3 traffic is coming from.

I'd love to know if anyone has had any resolution to this issue or any further details why it might be occurring.